# Convert varchar into datetime in oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime, type-conversion

My datetime is saved in database as varchar in "o" format.

Example:

```
2020-10-08T06:58:54.0000000+02:00
```

What is the appropriate format for this kind of data?
I want convert it to datetime.

Comment: Is your column data type is VARCHAR?

Comment: Yes it is a varchar column

Comment: Do not ignore the time zone when you convert your data. If you want to convert it to a `DATE` data type (which does not support time zones) then you should also convert all the values to a single common time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your data model! Do not store dates as strings; this is inefficient (you need to convert the string to a date whenever you want to perform artihmetic operation), and unsafe (you cannot guarantee that the values are valid dates).

As for your question: it depends the datatype you want to convert that string to. Assuming that you want `timestamp with time zone`, which seems like the most relevant option here (it allows fractional seconds and a time zone):

```
select to_timestamp_tz(
    '2020-10-08T06:58:54.0000000+02:00', 
    'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff tzh:tzm'
) as myts
from dual
```

This returns this `timestamp with time zone`:

```
08-OCT-20 06.58.54.000000000 +02:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Do **NOT** naively convert date-time values with a time zone to a date-time and ignore the time zone if you wish comparisons of those date-time-timezone values to still be accurate.

Your value has a time zone so the most natural method of storing the data would be `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and to convert it you can use:

```sql
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( your_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF7TZH:TZM' )
```

However, if you want the value as a `DATE` data type then this data type does not support time zones and you should convert all the values to a common time zone (typically this would be the UTC time zone) using:

```sql
CAST(
  TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( your_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF7TZH:TZM' )
  AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
  AS DATE
)
```

If you do not use a common time zone then you will find that you can compare values and draw incorrect comparisons.

For example:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( '2020-10-08T06:58:54.0000000+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF7TZH:TZM' )
            < TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( '2020-10-08T07:58:54.0000000+02:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF7TZH:TZM' )
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END AS comparison
FROM   DUAL
```

and

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN CAST(
              TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( '2020-10-08T06:58:54.0000000+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF7TZH:TZM' )
              AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
              AS DATE
            )
            < 
            CAST(
              TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( '2020-10-08T07:58:54.0000000+02:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF7TZH:TZM' )
              AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
              AS DATE
            )
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END AS comparison
FROM   DUAL
```

Both output:

> ```
> | COMPARISON |
> | ---------: |
> |          0 |
> ```

However, naively using `TO_DATE`:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN TO_DATE( '2020-10-08T06:58:54.0000000+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS##############' )
            < TO_DATE( '2020-10-08T07:58:54.0000000+02:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS##############' )
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END AS comparison
FROM   DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | COMPARISON |
> | ---------: |
> |          1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9f63b6699b6c39ad3051a8aada5c0270)*

Answer (score 0):

If your column is varchar2 and dates are stores in the string then you can use TO_DATE to convert it to date as follows:

```
SQL> SELECT TO_DATE('2020-10-08T06:58:54.0000000+02:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.#############')
  2    FROM DUAL;

TO_DATE('2020-10-08T
--------------------
08-oct-2020 06:58:54

SQL>
```

`#` is used to skip the character. I am ignoring the timezone and millisecond part as while converting to Date(&Time) it is not needed.